# Simple Layer 2 Bridge

Tags: networking, network-bridge

I’m looking to make a very simple WiFi to Ethernet Layer 2 bridge. The WiFi dongle I have supports AP mode and adding 4addr has been done successfully. Is there a simple script or process to creating this bridge? Most posts I’ve seen use a Layer 3 bridge, which won’t work as well for my intended application (streaming through a Sonos speaker). Multicast works but the Sonos app can’t find the device due to MAC addressing issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user iproute2 - the standard in most linux distros these days.

create a bridge and bring the bridge up

```
ip link add name br0 type bridge
ip link set br0 up
```

then add the devices you want to bridge:

```
ip link set wlan0 master br0 
ip link set eth1 master br0
```

you can view the links assigned to the bridge with

```
bridge link
```

note: you should assign the IP address to the bridge, and not each interface.  If you are wanting broadcast and multicast to go from ethernet to wireless, you will need to make the link promisc.  Wifi does not do multicast, however it can convert multicast to unicast.

```
ip link set eth1 promisc on
```

you might also need to enable mutlicast forwarding

```
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.mc_forwarding=1 
or just the enable it on the bridge
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.br0.mc_forwarding=1
```

I would suggest using hostapd, instead of trying to configure iw to connect with a bridge.

an example config for hostapd is:

/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
wpa=2
# Below line adds wlan0 to the bridge before the wifi is established
bridge=br0
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
hw_mode=g
channel=6
ieee80211n=1
wmm_enabled=1
ht_capab=[HT40][SHORT-GI-20][DSSS_CCK-40]
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0

# Change below lines to be your ssid and pass.
ssid=wifi_ap
wpa_passphrase=password
```

You will need to add br0 in interfaces, or the config of management service for your network, eg netplan or NetworkManager.

Adding the following lines in your /etc/network/interfaces should work:

```
auto br0
iface br0 manual
  bridge_ports eth1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed guide! I'm very new to Linux so this would've taken a ton of tinkering, I really appreciate the help!

Comment: these command worked individually, but I lost all network access after running the last 'bridge link.' Does something else have to be enabled? I'm using a USB WiFi adapter that supports AP mode, so to use it as a bridge I had to first type: iw dev uap0 set 4addr on

Comment: @cdubs I have added some extra info to the answer, I suggest you use hostapd, as that will do the setup of the bridge for you.

Comment: sorry for the delay, I've now tried what you described and receive the following error when testing hostapd:

Comment: sudo /usr/sbin/hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
Driver does not support configured HT capability [DSSS_CCK-40]
wlan1: interface state UNINITIALIZED->DISABLED
wlan1: AP-DISABLED
wlan1: Unable to setup interface.
wlan1: interface state DISABLED->DISABLED
wlan1: AP-DISABLED
wlan1: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan1 wasn't started
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan1 disabled_11b_rates=0

Comment: @cdubs run "iw list" Look for "Band 1:                Capabilities: " Under these headings you will have a list of Capabilities.  Your device doesnt support DSSS_CCK-40.  If iw list shows RX STBC 1-stream then replace [DSSS_CCK-40] with  [RC-STBC1].  If you are still having trouble, please paste the output of Capabilities section from iw list here, for me to assist further

Comment: Ah ok got it, thank you! Maybe I'll approach this from a different angle: everything works until I get to your Multicast forwarding step, to which I receive an 'invalid argument error.' Is this now when I'm supposed to use hostapd to finish the configuration?

Comment: I assume it is on the step sysctl net.ipv4.conf.br0.mc_forwarding=1 that you get the error?  you need to make sure you have creaatted the bridge interfae br0, you are correct this is created by hostapd.  just check systemd to ensure hostapd is set to enabled, then it should load at boot and create the bridge.  Have you added the linesto /etc/network/interfaces yet? that also should create a bridge

Comment: Got it, here's what I have so far for the hostapd configuration file: `interface=wlx00c0cab46ac3
bridge=br0
ssid=Home-Wade
hw_mode=g
channel=7
wmm_enabled=0
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=*****(hidden from this post)
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP`

Comment: interfaces file is then:                                                                                                    `auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
 bridge_ports wlx00c0cab46ac3 eth0`

Comment: Last comment: I must be pretty close to the end here, because when running `nmcli device status` it says wlx00c0cab46ac3 is in a disconnected state. It also returns no networks when running `nmcli device wifi list`

Comment: I have not used Network Manager with Hostapd.  so I am unsure what state it should be in before hostapd starts.  if you check iwctl it should show the device is powered. Also check rfkill to make sure the device is unblocked.  Then run hostapd from the command line if you are using default locations then /usr/sbin/hostapd -B -P /run/hostapd.pid /etc/hostapd/hostapd.con and that will show you any errors.

Comment: Gotcha, here's what I get when running hostapd from the command line: `nl80211: Could not configure driver mode
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlx00c0cab46ac3 disabled_11b_rates=0
nl80211 driver initialization failed.
wlx00c0cab46ac3: interface state UNINITIALIZED->DISABLED
wlx00c0cab46ac3: AP-DISABLED 
wlx00c0cab46ac3: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING 
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlx00c0cab46ac3 wasn't started`

Comment: I now replaced `driver=nl80211` with `driver=mt76x2u`, as I confirmed this was the driver being utilized by the card, but I get an error saying `invalid/unknown driver 'mt76x2u'` even though lsmod shows it installed. `Line 2: invalid/unknown driver 'mt76x2u'
1 errors found in configuration file '/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf'
Failed to set up interface with /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
Failed to initialize interface`